# sankey highchart - Pulando colunas

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estou implementando um Sankey Diagram usando o Highcharts JS e estou tentando colocar uma linha que acessa a primeira coluna para a terceira coluna. Isso é possível?

Por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/18/ 
Nesse caso, estou tentando colocar uma linha do Brasil para a Alemanha, mas não mova a Alemanha para a segunda coluna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplesmente adicionar `['Brazil', 'Germany', 2 ],` não resolve? (http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/91/)

Foi criada uma linha do Brasil para Alemanha e a mesma continua na terceira coluna.